# Summing hours between range of dates, looking up to separate table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In cells A1:B6 I have the following info.

```
Weekday     Hours
Monday      5
Tuesday     5
Wednesday   0
Thursday    5
Friday      0
```

In cells A8:B9 I have a date range, e.g.

```
From:       To:
09/01/19    11/01/19
```

In cell C9 I want a formula which tells me how many hours are between the from and to dates. Not the total number of hours, but the sum of hours as they appear in the weekday table.

There is a helpful article on exceljet which got me some of the way [here.](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-day-of-week-between-dates), but I got tangled in the array formulas and could not fix it.

The result of the formula should be: 5. ie. there are 5 hours between Wednesday 09/01/2019 and Friday 11/01/2019. (dd/mm/yy)

Any help is gratefully received.

Comment: Are your dates `mm/dd/yy` or `dd/mm/yy`?

Comment: Thanks Scott for fixing the formatting of the lists, I wasn't sure how to do that.

Comment: Dates are dd/mm/yy

Comment: Can it be more than a week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,TEXT(ROW(INDEX(XFA:XFA,D2):INDEX(XFA:XFA,E2)),"dddd")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your response, which works, but I don't understand why. What is the XFA:XFA referring to and why does it work? Thanks.

Comment: Also, is it possible to translate this into table references, rather than whole columns?

Comment: You can use table refs, change the `A:A` and `B:B` to the table references.  But leave the `ROW(INDEX(XFA:XFA,D2):INDEX(XFA:XFA,E2))` which is a counter that when iterates, iterates from the start date to the end date.  To excel a date is only a number that is masked to look like a date.  So we create a range from the row number the represents the start date to the row number that represents the end date and return an array of all the numbers between, representing the days between the start and finsih.  This array is passed to the text formula and then the days to the SUMIFS.

Comment: Great Scott! That makes sense and works, thank you very much.